Appimage trouble 23.10
Alright, so I installed libfuse2, rebooted then made the appimage exutable in properties, and when I double click on appimage nothing happens so I right click and open folder in terminal and run chmod +x appimage hit enter then run ./appimage and an error that say can't run binary. Do I need to take the appimage out of the downloads folder, or right click on the desktop and set something up? What confuses me is that I watched leeps video about running an emulator for ps2 and I had to Install the fuse and re download the desktop as in his video. Followed his steps and was able to run the app image. Other than that one appimage I have been unsuccessful downloading any other appimages other than from the app store on ubuntu itself. Any help understanding how to be able to run appimages I download from the internet would greatly be appreciated. I'm new with ubuntu but really like it compared to windows.

Can you share a link to the appimage? It may be an appimage specific error and we need to look at it to answer.

https://github.com/SoftFever/OrcaSlicer

Can you post the exact error message when you run ./OrcaSlicer_Linux_V2.0.0.AppImage ?
